# How to add data to different model class android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm newbie about android programming and Today I want to add data to another model class

and in another class model is same model

but I have no idea to add it

example

my first model

```
public class TelephoneModel {
 private List<DataBean> data;
 public List<DataBean> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<DataBean> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public static class DataBean {
        private String id;
        private String name;

 public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
}
```

and my second model

```
public class TelephoneDetailModel {
private List<DataBean> data;
  public List<DataBean> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<DataBean> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public static class DataBean {
  private String id;
        private String name;

 public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
}
}
```

and I have data in

```
List<TelephoneModel.DataBean> databeans = new ArrayList<>;
List<TelephoneDetailModel.DataBean> dataDetailbeans = new ArrayList<>;
```

and I want to add data `databeans` to `dataDetailbeans`

How to add it ,please give example for me,

thanks!

Comment: 1. delete any one of them 'TelephoneModel' or 'TelephoneDetailModel'. 2. add data to any one of the lists whenever required.

Comment: Use dataDetailbeans.addAll(databeans) to add all entries from list 'databeans' to 'dataDetailbeans'.

Comment: @PrakhaRaM Use dataDetailbeans.addAll(databeans) to add all entries from list 'databeans' to 'dataDetailbeans' >>> can not use it

Comment: delete anyone one of the model, use any one of the model, both are same with different names only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - Try this

```
List<TelephoneDetailModel.DataBean> databeans = new ArrayList();

        TelephoneDetailModel.DataBean dataBean = new TelephoneDetailModel.DataBean();
        dataBean.setId("1");
        dataBean.setName("PREM");
        databeans.add(dataBean);


        TelephoneDetailModel.DataBean model1 = new TelephoneDetailModel.DataBean();
        model1.setId("2");
        model1.setName("PREM2");
        databeans.add(model1);


        TelephoneDetailModel.DataBean model2 = new TelephoneDetailModel.DataBean();
        model2.setId("3");
        model2.setName("PREM3");
        databeans.add(model2);


        TelephoneDetailModel.DataBean model3 = new TelephoneDetailModel.DataBean();
        model3.setId("4");
        model3.setName("PREM4");
        databeans.add(model3);


        for (int i = 0; i < databeans.size(); i++) {

            Log.e("ID", databeans.get(i).getId());
            Log.e("NAME", databeans.get(i).getName());
        }
```

> **Out put**

```
com.example.user33.demoapplication E/ID: 1
com.example.user33.demoapplication E/NAME: PREM
com.example.user33.demoapplication E/ID: 2
com.example.user33.demoapplication E/NAME: PREM2
com.example.user33.demoapplication E/ID: 3
com.example.user33.demoapplication E/NAME: PREM3
com.example.user33.demoapplication E/ID: 4
com.example.user33.demoapplication E/NAME: PREM4
```

> - Try this

```
public class TelephoneDetailModel {

    private List<DataBean> data;

    public List<DataBean> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<DataBean> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public static class DataBean {
        private String id;
        private String name;

        public DataBean() {

        }

        public DataBean(String id, String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

> now to add data in your `arraylist` try this

```
List<TelephoneDetailModel.DataBean> databeans = new ArrayList();
databeans.add(new TelephoneDetailModel.DataBean("6","NEW NAME"));
```

Comment: thank! and if i have data size > 1 ,I have to write all this ? omg

Answer (score 4):

Hello change your model class like this (it is so simple to use)

--> TelephoneModel

```
public class TelephoneModel {

private String id;
private String name;

public TelephoneModel(String id,String name) {
    this.id=id;
    this.name=name;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

--> TelephoneDetailModel

```
public class TelephoneDetailModel {

public TelephoneDetailModel(String id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

private String id;
private String name;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

--> your activity

```
ArrayList<TelephoneModel> databeans = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<TelephoneDetailModel> dataDetailBeans = new ArrayList<>();

    // add data into databean

    databeans.add(new TelephoneModel("id-1", "name-1"));
    databeans.add(new TelephoneModel("id-2", "name-2"));

    // now add data databeans to dataDetailbeans

    for (int i = 0; i < databeans.size(); i++) {
        dataDetailBeans.add(new TelephoneDetailModel(databeans.get(i)
                .getId(), databeans.get(i).getName()));
    }
```

if any question then free to ask me...

Answer (score 1):

DataBean in TelephoneModel class and TelephoneDetailModel is different, you can't add the Datadean to another list